# VSCode 1.14.0 July update has major issues: How to roll back?

Tags: visual-studio-code

So with the new VSCode update version 1.14.0 it causes major issues which are

- High CPU usage (causes freezes)
- random crashes
- extensions are not availabe
- IntelliSense working half of the time

So my question is how can I roll VSCode back to the previous version without losing my configurations?

Comment: There is a thread about this at https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/30486 with people comparing data to solve the problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After 1.14.0 I have the same issues, specifically freezing for multiple seconds randomly during intellisense. They label it the previous month, so 1.14.0 is the "June" release.

Going to https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_13 and click the links right below the title to download the older versions (don't click the green download button).[image]

Downloading that windows executable for 1.13.1 and running it installed the old version over the new version without issue. All of my settings are the same and everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

### Update April 2021

To find the previous version, click the Updates link on the top nav

Then click the correct link for your platform - that will download the *latest* update for that version.

[image]

#### Note:

After downloading the previous version (1.54.3 system) and reinstalling overtop the current (more recent) version, I received an error from the Python extension:

> Cannot activate the Python extension because it depends on the Jupyter extension, which is not loaded.

Somehow the Jupyter extension was damaged and it was necessary to reinstall the Jupyter extension *(that extension was greyed-out in the Extensions pane - it was only necessary to click the gear icon beside the Jupyter extension and install the latest version)*. After that, everything worked.

So, not completely painless, but it was easily resolved.